# If a point in an image lies inside the sector of the circle or not?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, gesture-recognition

I have divided the concerned image into 12 equal sections. My task is to find out points of each section and then mark them. I have written a code which is working fine for some images but not for others. I am not able to find out the reason. 
Here is the code,

```
cent = regionprops(croppedImage,'Centroid');
cent = cat(1,cent.Centroid);
figure;
imshow(croppedImage)
hold on;
plot(cent(1,1),cent(1,2),'r*')
contoor = edge(croppedImage,'sobel');
[ril,cil] = find(contoor == 1);
contoor_w = [ril,cil];
contoor_s = size(contoor);

a = linspace(0, 2*pi, 13);
a_s = size(a');
contoor_s = size(contoor);
r = round(((contoor_s(1,1)/2 + contoor_s(1,2)/2)/2)+6);
x = cent(1,1) + r*cos(a);
y = cent(1,2) + r*sin(a);
figure;
imshow(contoor);
hold on;
plot(x,y)
for k = 1:x_s(1,2)-1
    P1 = [cent(1,1), cent(1,2)];
    P2 = [x(1,k),y(1,k)];
    P3 = [x(1,k+1), y(1,k+1)];
    P12 = P1-P2;
    P23 = P2-P3;
    P31 = P3-P1;
    s = det([P1-P2;P3-P1]);
    contoor_w_s = size(contoor_w);
    important = zeros(contoor_w_s(1,1),2);
    for i = 1:contoor_w_s(1,1)
        P = [contoor_w(i,1), contoor_w(i,2)];
        if (s*det([P3-P;P2-P3])>=0 & s*det([P1-P;P3-P1])>=0 & s*det([P2-P;P1-P2])>=0)
            important(i,:) = P;
        end
    end
    figure;
    imshow(contoor)
    hold on;
    plot(important(:,2),important(:,1),'g*') 
end
```

[croppedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ajo.jpg)
For this image, results are not coming.
Result for this image is given below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtmJR.jpg)
More elaborative results for each iteration in "k' loop:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIKrU.png)

[croppedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rT8c.jpg)
For this image, the code is working properly.
Result for this image is given below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgzZP.jpg)
More elaborative results for each iteration in "k' loop:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E33JZ.png)

I also tried checking the condition of sum of areas instead of determinant but all same and could not find out the reason. All this I have done using the help from similar questions posted on this platform but I am not able to solve this problem in particular.

If anybody can find out the reason why the code is not working on first picture and what is the solution to solve it, then it will be really helpful.

Comment: Have a look on inbuilt function _inpolygon_. This will tell you whether point lies inside or not.

Comment: I have added the images of result for both the hand images. I want to get sector specific points in variable "important" in the code and want to display it with green *. the loop will "for k = 1:x_s(1,1)" will be for all the sectors that is 12 for this case. So after the loop is complete, the hand should show every point in the boundary marked by green *.

Comment: Siva Srinivas Kolukula inpolygon is doing the same thing. The problem is that I am getting points for every sector of the circle that are inside it(shown as green * in result image) for some images. But not getting points for some sectors of the circle while using any the image as shown in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for it. The line of the above code

```
P = [contoor_w(i,1), contoor_w(i,2)];
```

should be

```
P = [contoor_w(i,2), contoor_w(i,1)];
```